# Weird behavior of external stylesheet

Tags: html, css

So I have an internal CSS in between style tags in the `<head>`, and I decided to move it to an external CSS file and then use a simple link.
So the thing is that if I use the external CSS one floated element goes to the next line, while in the internal this does not happen. The internal and external stylesheets are identical, indeed I copied and pasted the internal into an external file.
 I already rechecked 10 times that they are identical. The only difference is that one is internal while the other external.
Why is this happening?(look carefully at the jump of h2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>helo</title>
    <style>
        body, div, h1, h2, form
        {
            border:0;
            margin:0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        div.nav
        {
            height: 70px;
            left: 0;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        div.nav_body
        {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 1330px;
            min-width: 920px;
            padding: 0 20px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        div.nav_body h2
        {
            float: right;            
        }

        div.nav_body h2 a
        {
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 70px;
        }

        div.nav_body h1 a
        {
            font-size: 32px;
        }

        div.nav_body h1
        {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }

        div.form_container
        {
            margin-top: 70px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='nav'>
        <div class='nav_body'>
            <h1><a href='#'>welcome</a></h1>
            <h2><a href='#'>register</a></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form_container'>
        <div class='form_header'>
            <h1>register</h1>
        </div>

        <a href='forgot_password.php'>forgot</a>

        <div class='form_field'>
            <form>
                <input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email' />
                <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' />
                <input type='submit' value='log in' />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add your code with question

Comment: try saving your files and make sure you currently import the external file. Code will also help us, help you

Comment: I'll try to add code in a minute

Comment: Most likely your external style sheet does either not get loaded at all (check that in the browsers debugging console), or it is loaded at a different order location compared to before which might lead to changed priorities of the css rules. Again you can check those rules in the development console.

Comment: sorry for delay. Try to do this with an external style sheet and see what happened with the h2 element. It goes to next line.

Comment: Not reproduceable. You should show the code that does *not* work and explain clearly what you regard as the problem (“goes to next line” is obscure when there are just isolated words here and there. Also mention the browser(s) tested.

Answer (score 0):

It's working with external css

Your html file

```
   <!DOCTYPE html> <html>
<head>
    <title>helo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class='nav'>
        <div class='nav_body'>
            <h1><a href='#'>welcome</a></h1>
            <h2><a href='#'>register</a></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form_container'>
        <div class='form_header'>
            <h1>register</h1>
        </div>

        <a href='forgot_password.php'>forgot</a>

        <div class='form_field'>
            <form>
                <input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email' />
                <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' />
                <input type='submit' value='log in' />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
 body, div, h1, h2, form
        {
            border:0;
            margin:0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        div.nav
        {
            height: 70px;
            left: 0;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        div.nav_body
        {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 1330px;
            min-width: 920px;
            padding: 0 20px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        div.nav_body h2
        {
            float: right;            
        }

        div.nav_body h2 a
        {
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 70px;
        }

        div.nav_body h1 a
        {
            font-size: 32px;
        }

        div.nav_body h1
        {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }

        div.form_container
        {
            margin-top: 70px;
        }
```

Comment: look at the <h2><a href='#'>register</a></h2>, it goes to next line

Comment: now it gives same result with external and internal (edited )

Comment: seems that it was an issue with the closing of the body tag

Comment: Yes i think because it was the only thing that i added in your code